# get components inside jscrollpane in a jinternal frame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

How to get any content inside a j scroll pane which is added to a j internal frame

Basically, what i have a j table which is made from data in sql...the j internal frame has the name of the table...i want to get the name of the table whenever user wants to edit table....j table is in j scroll pane..and that scroll pane is inside j internal frame...
i want to get selected j internal frame from the desktop pane...get the scroll pane inside it...and then get the j table inside the scrollpane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... i want to get selected j internal frame from the desktop pane...

Read the `JDesktopPane` API. You will find a method that gets the currently selected internal frame.

> get the scroll pane inside it

Components are added to the "content pane" of the internal frame. So you need to get the content pane and then you can get the components added to it. Read the JInternalFrame and Container API's for the methods to get the content pane and then the components.

> and then get the j table inside the scrollpane

Read the `JScrollPane` API. You will find a method that allows you to get the component added to the "viewport" of the scroll pane.

I would start with the "getter" methods.